# Show alert before confirmation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to display an alert first and then show the confirmation box.
The alert should only be displayed if the treeview contains childnodes.

Here is my code so far, the code shows confirmation box first and then alert. Is there any way to switch them around so the alert is shown before confirmation?

```
//shows the confirmation box
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {              
                        btn_save_delete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Deleting the Selected Item will also delete any existing Children under it! Confirm Changes?');");
                   }
```

//shows the alert message

```
protected void btn_save_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (tree_items.SelectedNode.ChildNodes.Count >= 1)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.tree_items, typeof(string), "Alert", "alert('Message here');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.tree_items, typeof(string), "Alert", "alert('Message here2');", true);
            }
}
```

Thank you

Further detail:

I have a tree view and a delete button on the webpage.
The tree view loads with parent nodes and child nodes.
If I click on delete after selecting a parent node with child nodes, it should give me an alert and then a confirmation box. If I select a child node or a parent node without any child nodes then it should only show me the confirmation box.

Comment: You may need to provide more information if you want your question answered. I find this too vague to be able to grasp what you're doing.   Try providing an overview, and explaining what the first bit of code is.

Comment: change your typeof(string) to this.GetType() follow my example below.. works for me.. let me know if it works

Comment: @ArmedMonkey I have added details to the explanation, let me know if you require further detail

Answer (score 0):

why not try to format your Alert..try this you will need to change the Alert message to fit your example...//strExport  is what you will assign your alert message..

```
string script = "alert('" + strExport + "');";
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
```

Comment: It does not work at all. This is how I put it: string script = "alert('" + "Hi" + "');";
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);

Comment: well it works for me.. I am passing in a string not doing the quotedString ... mabe there is something else wrong.. what's your javascript call look like..?